# validate uniqueness of polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a validation for a polymorphic association, where I only want it to trigger on a certain type. Which is user.

I'd want something like this:

```
validates :room_id, uniqueness: { scope: tokenable_id if tokenable type is User }
```

how do I go about doing this. The other type is Customer. Which I want to allow the opportunity to be several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [Conditional Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless)

> Sometimes it will make sense to validate an object only when a given
>   predicate is satisfied. You can do that by using the :if and :unless
>   options, which can take a symbol, a string, a Proc or an Array. You
>   may use the :if option when you want to specify when the validation
>   should happen. If you want to specify when the validation should not
>   happen, then you may use the :unless option.

**5.1 Using a Symbol with :if and :unless**

> You can associate the :if and :unless options with a symbol
>   corresponding to the name of a method that will get called right
>   before validation happens. This is the most commonly used option.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :room_id, uniqueness: { scope: :tokenable_id }, if: :is_right_type?

  # or maybe this will work
  validates :room_id, uniqueness: { scope: :tokenable_id }, if: :user?

  def is_right_type?
    type == "user"
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you can also give a string option to `:if`, e.g. `id: "type == 'user'"`